# fetch only fully matched results by bootstrap-table-filter-control

Tags: filter, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I searched a lot to find the filter option done by bootstrap-table-filter-control to get the exact matched output rather than from the partial matched output,but i couldn't got an solution for this.Is there any method?

Comment: is `filterStrictSearch` applicable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take this fiddle for example (without strict search):

```
https://jsfiddle.net/eitanmg/ao5ybwvr/1/
```

and this fiddle (with strict search):

```
https://jsfiddle.net/eitanmg/ao5ybwvr/2/
```

When search for the number 219 in the search text box, if `filterStrictSearch` is `false` the results will be both rows that match 219 and 2199. And when `filterStrictSearch` is `true` the result will be only 219.

if you are passing the `filterStrictSearch: true` via html it become `data-strict-search="true"`